How to guide (force?) future developers to use a derived class
I'm working on an extension to a vendor application that provides APIs for this purpose. Among these APIs are various UI elements that (among other things) send stack traces back to the application vendor whenever they catch an exception. Let's consider the VendorCommand class (which implements ICommand) for a quasi-concrete example.  I would like to avoid leaking our extension's exceptions to the vendor, so I have created a derived class that all of our UI elements should use instead of VendorCommand. Something like this . . .
/// <summary>
/// Wraps the actions and functions injected into a <see cref="VendorCommand"/> with try...catch.
/// This does two things:
///     1) Prevents IDWR stack traces leaking to the software vendor, and
///     2) Ensures that exceptions in view models are logged
/// </summary>
public class MyCustomCommand : VendorCommand
{/* I'll avoid boring you and embarrassing myself */}

I would like to provide forceful encouragement to the people who follow me that they should use MyCustomCommand instead of VendorCommand. Is there a way to provide a build error/warning when someone uses VendorCommand, or some other approach that will light up an IDE? I'm looking for something more than a note in the readme, which is already miles long and full of useful tidbits that no one ever reads.
Googling this question netted unhelpful things like:

"Make the base class abstract," which of course doesn't work in my scenario since I don't have control over that.
Discussions regarding how to get a derived class's member in the base class


I don't suggest forcing developers to implement any derived types with compile-time errors or similar restrictions. Developers should have the freedom to make mistakes and learn. However, it's recommended to use compile-time errors for scenarios like detecting unused variables, not awaited Task methods, or unused namespaces.
On the other hand, when a developer implements a specific use case within your system, it needs to be registered. For example, services.AddScoped<ICommand, MyCommand>(). If a developer wishes to utilize this use case within your system, they should adhere to the policies you provide. This is where you should enforce the implementation of your specific class. In summary, use generics when developers need to register their class into your system.
services.AddCustomeCommandIntoMySystem<TCommand>(this IServiceCollection services, TCommand c) where TCommand : class, MyCustomeCommand
{...}


The application I'm extending manages the lifetimes of their classes and the API doc is full of warnings not to register their classes within extensions' IoC containers, so this may be difficult to implement in my case.  I'll have to experiment...

So you are building an IOC framework or something?

Goodness no! I'm using .NET6's in-built IoC container to manage all my classes' lifetimes. The entry point for my extension and all of the UI (all classes provided by the vendor) are managed by the vendor application itself. Vendor guidance is to give the entry point access to the IoC container, and access all dependencies statically from there. The vendor has created a custom implementation of ICommand, and their guidance is to new it up as-needed in view models. I have extended that custom implementation as described in the question.
